# detecting user input with QTextEdit (& distinguishing it from application changes)

Tags: c++, linux, c++11, qt5

Gtk3 rich [text widget](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/TextWidget.html) machinery (based upon [GtkTextBuffer](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html) & [GtkTextView](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextView.html)) has both ["begin-user-action"](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#GtkTextBuffer-begin-user-action) and ["end-user-actions"](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkTextBuffer.html#GtkTextBuffer-begin-user-action) signals, which permits quickly to process user input conveniently (and distinguish it from *application* generated changes to the buffer or the view).

But it looks like there is no similar stuff in Qt5. For example, my incomplete understanding is that  [QTextEdit::insertHtml](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextedit.html#insertHtml) or [QTextDocument::contentsChange](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#contentsChange) or [QTextDocument::contentsChanged](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtextdocument.html#contentsChanged) does not separate changes related to user input (either keyboard, or pasting, etc...) from those done by the application.

What I have in mind is some syntax oriented editor.

I'm probably misunderstanding Qt5 rich text editor support.

<sup>(For curious people: I am redesigning & reimplementing my [MELT monitor](https://github.com/bstarynk/melt-monitor-2015) with C & GTK into something with C++11 & Qt5 tentatively called [Basixmo](https://github.com/bstarynk/basixmo); all is GPL free software, but I have not coded yet the Qt5 thing)</sup>

#### example

I have a window with a button `say` and a `QTextEdit` as its central widget. When I click the button, a `"hello"`  string is inserted in the document, and I call that an *application* change (you could imagine that the button is replaced by something unrelated to the user, e.g. some network input). When I type some keypresses into the text-editor, some string is also inserted from that *user-action* change. I want to distinguish both.

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QTextEdit>
#include <QToolBar>
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
int main(int argc, char**argv)
{
  QApplication app(argc, argv);
  auto win = new QMainWindow;
  auto tb = win->addToolBar("Basile example");
  auto ted = new QTextEdit;
  win->setCentralWidget(ted);
  tb->addAction("say",[=]{ted->insertPlainText("hello");});
  auto doc = ted->document();
  QObject::connect(doc,&QTextDocument::contentsChange,
                   [=](int pos, int removedchars, int addedchars)
                      { std::clog << "contentChange: pos=" << pos
                                  << " removedchars=" << removedchars
                                  << " addedchars=" << addedchars
                                  << std::endl; });
  win->show();
  app.exec();
  delete win;
}


//// Local Variables:
//// compile-command: "g++ -std=c++11 -Wall -g $(pkg-config --cflags Qt5Core Qt5Widgets Qt5Gui) -fPIC $(pkg-config --libs Qt5Core Qt5Widgets Qt5Gui) -o eqb eqb.cc"
//// End:
```

But when I run the above code, the `contentsChange`  signal (connected to my lambda function outputting to `std::clog`) is triggered for both user-action changes and application changes.

I don't care to work at the `QTextEdit`, or `QTextDocument` or `QTextCursor` level, but I want to separate user-action changes (typing into the `QTextEdit` widget, or pasting with a mouse click & menu, etc...) from application changes. I would like to avoid working at widget events level (e.g. redefine a virtual member function for `QWidget::keyPressEvent` in my own class, and so on) in particular because I am not sure to know *all* the possible events affecting a `QTextEdit` instance.

BTW, a too broad generalization of my question might be : how to design & code an editor as scriptable as `emacs`  is using *genuine* Qt5 coding style and widgets in C++11 (of course by embedding some scriptable interpreter à la Guile).

<sup>PS. If that matters, my desktop system runs Debian/testing/x86-64. Qt is version 5.6.1, my code is compiled by GCC 6.2; the compilation command is in the last wide comment.</sup>

Answer (score 3):

In your specific case, the signals in which you are interested are emitted on the `QTextDocument` object that is part of the `QTextEdit`.
You can use a `QSignalBlocker` within your lambda to prevent those signals to be emitted:

```
#include <QSignalBlocker>

// ...

tb->addAction("say", [=]{
    const QSignalBlocker blocker{ted->document()};
    ted->insertPlainText("hello");
});
```

This way, you won't receive anymore the `contentsChange` signal when the  application *changes* the context of the document.

See the [official documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsignalblocker.html) for further details.

Note that signals on `QTextEdit` are not inhibited.
They are probably bound to the ones of the `QTextDocument` and propagated (you can see the code of the class if you are interested in these details).
If you want to differentiate between user changes and application changes, you can now extend the class and add custom signals to be emitted from within your lambda (as an example, `internalContentChange`).
Otherwise, call directly a method and that's all.
What to do mostly depends on the specific problem and on how the software has been designed.

---

As a side note and as mentioned in the comments, a few more details to better explain why it works.
The `QTextEdit` (let me say) *forwards* the `insertPlainText` request to the internal `QTextDocument`. As a consequence, the latter emits a signal that is (again, let me say) *caught and propagated* by the `QTextEdit`.
That's why the above described trick applies well in the specific case by inhibiting the signals on the internal class. In other terms, `QTextEdit` both has its own signals and acts as a re-emitter for some signals emitted by its components (mainly the `QTextDocument`).

I tried to stay simple for the sake of clarity, but you can follow the flow of the request and the signal by looking at the classes that are present [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets) (the public repository).
In particular, [here](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qtextedit.cpp#n2239) is where the `QTextEdit` component forwards the `insertPlainText` call to the internal [`QTextEditControl`](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qtextedit.cpp#n81) component, that is for itself a `QWidgetTextControl` and [forwards the call](http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qtbase.git/tree/src/widgets/widgets/qwidgettextcontrol.cpp#n3021) to the internal cursor... and so on.
Too long a trail to be fully analyzed here.

Comment: Interesting. I thought than in Qt like in GTK, most of the internal processing is also signal based. So how would that work?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch What do you mean with _how would that work_? I don't get you, sorry.

Comment: I thought that  `ted->insertPlainText("hello");` is *internally* using signals.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch More or less. It forwards the request to the internal `QTextDocument`. It the emits a signal that is caught and propagated by the `QTextEdit`. That's why you can do this trick in the specific case by inhibiting the signals on the internal class. In other terms, `QTextEdit` both has its own signals and acts as a forwarder for some signals emitted by its components.

Comment: I believe those details should go into your answer!

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Edited. Is it fine for you? I'm at your disposal for further details.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly different approach to [@skypjack's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40370181/4987285) may be to *tag* application changes instead of blocking them:

```
bool application_change = false;
tb->addAction("say",
    [=, &application_change]{
        application_change = true;
        ted->insertPlainText("hello");
        application_change = false;
    }
);

// ...

QObject::connect(doc, &QTextDocument::contentsChange,
    [=, &application_change](int pos, int removedchars, int addedchars){
        std::clog << "contentChange: pos=" << pos
            << " removedchars=" << removedchars
            << " addedchars=" << addedchars
            << std::endl;
        if(application_change)
            std::clog << "this is an application change" << std::endl;
    }
);
```

The switch on `application_change` may be wrapped into a locker:

```
struct BoolLocker
{
    bool& locked;

    BoolLocker(bool& to_lock_):
        locked(to_lock_)
    {
        locked = true;
    }

    ~BoolLocker(bool& to_lock_)
    {
        locked = false;
    }
};

// ...

bool application_change = false;
tb->addAction("say",
    [=, &application_change]{
        BoolLocker locker(application_change);
        ted->insertPlainText("hello");
    }
);
```

Or generated in a wrapping lambda through a factory function:

```
bool application_change = false;

template<typename F>
auto make_application_change(F&& f)
{
    return [&f]{
        application_change = true;
        f();
        application_change = false;
    };
}

// ...

tb->addAction("say",
    make_application_change(
        [=]{
            ted->insertPlainText("hello");
        }
    )
);
```

Note that this implementation is a basic example which should be adapted in a real use case. For example (as pointed in the comments), there may be issues in a multithread application.

Comment: This approach could have problems maybe in a multithreaded application. What if the application change happens on a secondary thread and on the UI thread you have an user input? The latter could be wrongly treated as an application change.

Comment: This is just a draft to show the idea. You're right to point the potential issues in a multithread context. I didn't mention them because that was not part of the OP

Comment: I would integrate the answer for these details, for they can be useful to the reader. Knowing pros and cons before to start is usually a good thing. ;-)